# In Django, when I run migrate I get the error : accounts_userinfo.user_id may not be NULL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, web-frameworks

Whenever I run python manage.py migrate accounts I get the error code : django.db.utils.IntegrityError: accounts_userinfo.user_id may not be NULL

I believe this is caused by me linking a model with more user information, with the django user model.
This is my models.py

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    c_site = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    link = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Does anybody see an obvious problem that I may be missing?
Let me know if you need any more code.
Thanks much.
-Ramsey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign keys cannot be null by default. You either need to make it nullable:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    c_site = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    link = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True)
```

Or set a default:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    c_site = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    link = models.ForeignKey(User, default = some_id)
```

This will depend if the `link` is required. It appears that is likely is required.

This happens because there is existing data in the database that does not have a value for this field (`link`) and Django cannot *guess*. Another option is to remove all entries in the `Users` and `UserInfo` tables (assuming the data is not in production) and then migrate.

If you're just trying to *make it work*, you can set the default to one of the existing user models, then go into the Django admin panel and correct the entries. The problem with this is that you will have to specify an ID (ie. `1`) which may not be present on other databases. But again, if this is still in development and no real data is being migrated, then you're fine.

The last option is to set it as nullable at first, then go into the data, create entries for everything, and then create another migration to remove the nullable attribute.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. How exactly would I set it an existing user model? I have nothing important in the database so I just got rid of everything but the problem is still occuring.
What should I set the default = to? 
Thanks much for your help!

Comment: Hmm, it's tough to tell without seeing _everything_. It seems like it could be related to the order that the migrations are being run. What database are you using? Did you try dropping the database entirely and running the migrate command again?

Comment: Besides that, I would recommend deleting the migration that fails, setting `null = True`, then creating another migration. At least see if that fixes the issue. You could just set the default to the ID of any User in the database. It's just an integer.

Comment: Thanks . I managed to make it work(kind of)
I can now access the table in admin, unfortunately, now I'm trying to link the initial user (django ) form with the UserInfo form by passing in the username so that the link is done correctly.
What I mean by that is the foreign key user will be set automatically to the username that has been entered right before going on to the userinfo form.
Do you get what I mean? Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: You'll have to open a new question for that, as it is unrelated. Django has documentation on the design pattern you're using. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model